# listings dot and slash chars appearance weird

Tags: listings

Say below document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
    \lstset{}
    \begin{lstlisting}
system/etc/selinux/
+-- selinux/
+-- mapping/
|  |-- 28.0.cil [94042]
|  |-- 29.0.compat.cil [165]
|  +-- 27.0.cil [80073]
|-- plat_mac_permissions.xml [8063]
+-- plat_sepolicy_and_mapping.sha256 [65]
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

It looks good in text format, but after compile to pdf, the dot and slash looks like a litter bit larger than other chars, the last two lines not aligned with the above one either (see the | not align).
Any special setup needed to make it align correctly?

[image]

I would like listings output the same format just as linux terminal:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get verbatim output, the simplest approach is to use LaTeX's `verbatim` environment:

```
\begin{verbatim}
system/etc/selinux/
+-- selinux/
+-- mapping/
|  |-- 28.0.cil [94042]
|  |-- 29.0.compat.cil [165]
|  +-- 27.0.cil [80073]
|-- plat_mac_permissions.xml [8063]
+-- plat_sepolicy_and_mapping.sha256 [65]
\end{verbatim}
```

which will switch to typewriter type and not interpret any special characters. I would only use `lstlisting` if you want to get the language-specific reformatting of the code.